# rails won't render error messages for failed validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't get rails to render any error messages. I have this code at the top of a form partial for a simple crud project.

```
 <% if @article.errors.any? %>
        
        <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @article.errors.each do |error| %>
                <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        
    <% end %>
```

and these are the validations inside of the model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum:100}
    validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 300}
end
```

when I try to save a new article in the web browser with the incorrect title and body length nothing happens. when I try to save an article manually in the console it fails and the errors are displayed when I enter `article.errors.full_messages`.I don't know why the errors won't display in the browser. Any advice is appreciated

edited- added controller and routes code

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_article, only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]
    
    def show
        
    end

    def index
        @articles = Article.all 
    end

    def new 
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
        
    end 

    def create 
       @article = Article.new(article_params)
       if @article.save
        flash[:notice] = "Article was created successfully!"
        redirect_to @article 

       else 
        render 'new'
       end
    end

    def update
        
        if @article.update(article_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Article was updated successfully!"
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy 
        
        @article.destroy
        flash[:alert] = "Article was deleted successfully!"
        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private

    def set_article
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params 
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def check_input

        
    end

    

        


end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  
  root "pages#home"

  resources :articles
  
end
```

Comment: Can you share your controller's code and maybe routes for a good measure?

Comment: I've added the code to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your articles controller create to:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to article_url(@article), notice: 'Article was successfully created.'

    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity

    end
  end
```

Explanation: render :new will render the new template, but it will also set the status code to 200 (OK). This is not what you want. You want to set the status code to 422 (Unprocessable Entity). This will tell the browser that the request was valid, but the server was unable to process it. This is what you want to happen when the validations fail.

Comment: When I use the second option I get an error that the @ article class is nil. I then put @ article = Article.new and ran it and now all messages are constantly displayed except any errors, because of the code above.

Comment: Test now. I did a test here and I think I found the problem.

Comment: you did it you son of a gun! It works. the error messages pop up when they should now. thanks for the help and the explanation.